# Get image from standard Android Gallery

Tags: image, android-intent, uri, gallery

I am having problems getting an image back from the default android gallery. All I want to do is call the Android standard gallery intent and return the uri for the image in my onActivityResult. When I run this code it open the gallery just fine but then it force closes whenever I click on a picture. Any tips for this would be helpful.

```
private void doGallery() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType(IJudgeSingleton.IMAGEINTENT);
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Picture"), IJudgeSingleton.REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
}


case IJudgeSingleton.REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY:
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            mSingleton.mFileTemp = new File(getMediaPath(uri));
            try {
                IJudgeSingleton.copy(mSingleton.mFileTemp, mSingleton.mCropFileTemp);
                mData.setImageSet(true, mSingleton.mFileTemp.toURI().toString(), true);
                mData.setPhoto(true);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY", e);
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out my file was pointing to a null so that's what was giving me the force close. Also I had to add change some code around in my onActivityResult for REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY. I have posted the added code below for anyone who has this problem.

```
case IJudgeSingleton.REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY:

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            //This takes the uri/image returned from the gallery intent a places it into a file.

            final int chunkSize = 1024;  // We'll read in one kB at a time
            byte[] imageData = new byte[chunkSize];

            try {
                InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mSingleton.mFileTemp);  // I'm assuming you already have the File object for where you're writing to

                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = in.read(imageData)) > 0) {
                    out.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(imageData, 0, Math.max(0, bytesRead)));
                }
                in.close();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getName(),"REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY");

            }
        //  mSingleton.mFileTemp = new File(getMediaPath(uri));
            try {
                IJudgeSingleton.copy(mSingleton.mFileTemp, mSingleton.mCropFileTemp);
                mData.setImageSet(true, mSingleton.mFileTemp.toURI().toString(), true);
                mData.setPhoto(true);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY", e);
            }
            break;
        case IJudgeSingleton.REQUEST_CODE_DEFAULT_CAPTURE:
            mData = data.getParcelableExtra(IJudgeSingleton.SURVEY_INTENT);
            showListView();
            completedIntent = false;
```